# TRIGGER instead CHECK Clause in MySql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, triggers

MySql dont supported CHECK Clause so i think i must be to use TRIGGER on a Table 

in a simple Table we have two field that opinion field must be in ('normal','bad','good') :

```
CREATE TABLE `user`.`opinionTable` (
`uid` INT NOT NULL,
`opinion` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`opinion`),
 CHECK (opinion IN ('normal','bad','good'))
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

i want to check opinion data is a allowed value ('normal','bad','good') or no and when is not allowed i want to Transaction to Rollbacked
i tried this TRIGGER but not worked so  what is the correct TRIGGER statement ?

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_values BEFORE INSERT ON `opinionTable`
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.opinion IN ('normal','bad','good'))
            THEN
            END IF;
        END
```

i catch this exception :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
```

mysql version is 5.1.34 community
jdbc version is 5.1.23

Comment: Use an enum type for your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement check constraint, if the inputs are not matched.

1. Force to use default values.
2. `SIGNAL` an error and abort the transaction.

**Example 1**: ***Force to use default values***
You can define to use `default` value to silently use in case an invalid input is encountered.

```
IF ( LOWER( NEW.opinion ) NOT IN ('normal','bad','good')) THEN
  SET default_opinion := 'normal';  -- declare this field first
  NEW.opinion := default_opinion;  -- change its value as desired
ELSE
  NEW.opinion := LOWER( NEW.opinion );  -- change this as desired
END IF;
```

**Example 2**: ***`SIGNAL` an error and abort the transaction***
Define an error state number for the case and relevant error messages.
Use the same to `SIGNAL` the error.

```
IF ( LOWER( NEW.opinion ) NOT IN ('normal','bad','good')) THEN
  -- don't forget to declare variables first and then use
  SET error_message := CONCAT( 'Invalid opinion option: ', NEW.opinion );
  -- set proper error state number  --  302478 is just an example
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '302478' SET MESSAGE_TEXT := error_message;
END IF;
```

Comment: i defined a error_message variable before IF statement.DECLARE error_message VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT 'no error'. but i catch exception again :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (LOWER(NEW.opinion) NOT IN ('normal','bad','good')) THEN

Comment: Variable declaration must be just after `BEGIN` under `DECLARE` section. Then you can assign values conditionally after that.

Comment: yes , this is my code for throwing exception : http://fpaste.org/294290/14484440/

Comment: Each of the statements must be terminated by a semi colon. **`;`**. It is missing at the end of `DECLARE` statement.

Comment: after fixing , mysql again say me syntax error on SIGNAL SQLSTATE... so i searched and then i find my DB is not supported SIGNAL because it was depreciated so after upgrading to 5.7 it's worked as fine and Thanks a lot for your help